# Populate a customlist dropdown of sharepoint with another customlist-via webservice

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using SP Designer 2007. In SP Designer, I have placed my custom list(ApplicationForm), which has some text fields and some dropdowns, lets say name(textbox) and country(dropdown).

In the (country) dropdown control, the values are coming from the hard coded values, which are created while creating the custom list.

In the SharePoint site there is another custom list called ListOfCountries which has list of values. I need this custom list values to be populated in the dropdown(country).

I heard it can be done using webservices. I do not know how.

How do I populate this? I heard there is SPwebservice from codeplex, but not sure where to start.

Any ideas or example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are trying to fill a dropdown in a custom aspx form (as you said your are using sharepoint designer) from which you want to populate the values into the dropdown from a list which is present in the same site.

This is similar to creating a custom list/site column with an option called look up.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct. But instead of using lookup columns can I go for the Webservice method, As the look up columns had problems in importing from development to production server?

Comment: Yes, you can use webservice to bind to a control, but just to fill one dropdown do we really need a webservice? If you already have one webservice then you can use.